# Why scrapy fetch data sometime and sometime it doesn't?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have limited knowledge of Scrapy. I tried to write spider for indeed.

```
class ExecSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "indeed_uk"
    allowed_domains = ["indeed.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=%C2%A335,000&jt=contract',
    ]
```

sample link is below:

https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=5de17a782172c5b9&from=serp&vjs=3

My piece of code which is sometimes working sometimes not working is below:

```
salarystring = ''.join(map(lambda s:s.strip(),response.xpath('//div/span[@class = "no-wrap"]/text()').extract()))
            if salarystring is None:
                salarystring = ''.join(map(lambda s:s.strip(),response.xpath('//div[@class = "jobsearch-JobMetadataHeader-item "]/text()').extract()))
            print(salarystring)
```

Here I writed two xpath because on website before sometimes it was `'//div/span[@class = "no-wrap"]/text()'` and now it is `'//div[@class = "jobsearch-JobMetadataHeader-item "]/text()'`

logfile is below:

```
2018-08-10 14:09:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=20635031d9ceaad1&from=serp&vjs=3> (referer: https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=$30,000&l=United+States&jt=contract&explvl=mid_level)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imac086/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/Users/imac086/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/Users/imac086/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/Users/imac086/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/imac086/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/imac086/Documents/premal/test_interim_scrapper/interim/spiders/indeed.py", line 180, in parsejob
    print ('job rate ', item['job_rate'])
  File "/Users/imac086/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 59, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
KeyError: 'job_rate'
```

Can anyone please or tell me why is this happening in Scrapy it's working sometimes when I run same code 2-3 times?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: Thanks for comment. I edited my question and put log file piece where I am getting error

Comment: Seems like your spider is crashing on `print('job rate', item['job rate'])` part as your item has no `job rate` key. Try replacing with `print('job rate', item.get('job rate'))`

Comment: @Premalsheth note that `salarystring = ''.join(map(lambda s:s.strip(),response.xpath('//div/span[@class = "no-wrap"]/text()').extract()))` can never fulfil the `if salarystring is None` check to run the second xpath, as if there's nothing from the extract from the first string then `salarystring` will be equal to an empty string `''`...

Comment: It's also arguably more readable written as `''.join(el.strip() for el in response.css('div span.no-wrap::text').extract())`